# Separate Logfiles in Multithreaded Application

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I am working on an application that processes multiple files in a multithreaded fashion.
The analysis is done by starting one thread per file that should be analyzed and then working through a series of steps (in different classes) that all produce some form of logging output.

I would like to have dedicated logfile for each of the files I analyze that only contains the messages for that file. The code I am using right now was written when the program was still single-threaded:

```
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %C{1} %x - %m%n");
    if(Config.CREATE_SEPERATE_LOG)
    {

        FileAppender appender;
        try {
            String path = (Config.LOGFILE_PATH!=null)?Config.LOGFILE_PATH:filename;
            appender = new FileAppender(layout,path);
            appender.setErrorHandler(new FallbackErrorHandler());
            appender.setName("Dedicated Appender");
            org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Config.class).warn("Failed to create a dedicated log "+filename, e);
        }
    }
```

This basically creates an extra appender that writes to a dedicated logfile for the file under analysis. While it works worked back then when the application was single-threaded, it gets messed up.

How can I change my setup so I can have each class participating in the analysis of a certain file funnel its logging into a specific logfile for that file.

Comment: Have you tried using some sort of variable generated from the file you're reading to initiate the FileWriter (assuming you're using it) stream target?

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. Would you work around log4j and just use a plain old java FileWriter?

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that, just set the name of each thread (or a prefix + name).
Then use log4j `PatternLayout` to format each log line such that the thread name is output.
`%t` is the format symbol for thread name.
Further info in [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) docu:

> Let the conversion pattern be "%-5p [%t]: %m%n" and assume that the
>   log4j environment was set to use a PatternLayout.

My experience is, that it is more usefull  to separate the threads log into separate files afterwards, using a script that considers the thread name, if necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question properly, what I believe is you need to have custom logger for each thread. Each thread should point to own log file. If it is the case, you would be implementing/initialising your logger instatnce at thread class level.

```
public class MyThread  implements Runnable{
    private Logger logger =null;
public MyThread(){
    FileAppender appender =null;
    //custom initialisation code for specific appender/file
    logger =  // initialise 
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void warn(String message){
    logger.warn(message);
}
private void info(String message){
    logger.info(message);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I can just do Logger.getLogger("name-of-file-to-be-analyzed") in each class that is involved in the analysis of the file. Or would that prevent me from seeing where the log messages came from?